# IBM Cloud: Which API to use to get list of all block volume sanctioned

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, block-storage

Currently, I use [this IBM Cli](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-sl-block-storage) command to get list of volumes sanctioned:

```
ibmcloud sl block volume-list
```

I wanted to get the same data using IBM Cloud API (or Python SDK).

I tried [this IBM Cloud's VPC API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/vpc#list-volumes)
but that only seem to list disk under a VPC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official [IBM Cloud API list](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs?tab=api-docs&) does not seem to have any SoftLayer / Infrastructure APIs.

Running the following command with trace enabled

```
IBMCLOUD_TRACE=true ibmcloud sl block volume-list
```

shows that this API is called:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/mobile/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getIscsiNetworkStorage.json
```

You might want to test [getIscsiNetworkStorage](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getIscsiNetworkStorage/), even if it is a legacy API.